# Easiest way to send one-time string value from my winforms desktop app to my windows service

Tags: string, winforms, windows-services, ipc

Every time my windows forms desktop app starts up, I need it to send a one-time **string** value to my windows service on the same pc.
In most cases, the service will be running constantly even when the desktop app is not. But the desktop app will check and start the service if necessary.

What is the easiest/best mechanism for simple communication of a single string on desktop app startup to the windows service?
I have no idea how communication with windows service works.

Is there any simple example of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing and seems to be working so far is have my desktop app write my string value to a file in the CommonApplicationData special folder using:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

And then my Windows Service looks for the file and its value using the same method.

CommonApplicationData is the directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by **all users**, including the SYSTEM account.

For details, see [Environment.GetFolderPath Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=net-7.0) and CommonApplicationData in [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-7.0).